# Method for generating .net client code for a REST based web api

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-services, rest, asp.net-web-api

I'd like to access some web api's using .net code, but am not sure if there's a way to generate a client side wrapper of some kind for these? Perhaps a code generator that can look at the web api documentation or through sample calls and generated .net classes and methods to encapsulate the api?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't. REST-based APIs do not have a WSDL or service contract that could be used to generate a client stub.

That said, consider the following alternatives:

- [REST Coder](http://www.slideshare.net/hiranya911/restcoder): this is interesting research but no definitive tools yet.
- Google for .NET WCF REST client: it turns up a lot of interesting results.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there isn't.
However, you can try one of the many wrappers available, that makes your life easier once you have to write less code.

Check this one out I've written a few months ago:

http://webapiclient.azurewebsites.net